# Component definition is missing display name in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Rendering with map I have a double arrow function returning components and I get a missing display name error

Here is the code

```js
const Sales = (props: Props) => {
  const renderCard = React.useMemo(
    () => (config) => (card, i) => {
      return (
        <div {...config} key={i}>
          <Card Icon={card.Icon} label={card.label} />
        </div>
      );
    },
    [cards]
  );

  return (
    <div title="Sales">
      <div>
        {cards.slice(0, 3).map(renderCard(configOne))}
      </div>
      {/* other stuff */}
      <div>
        {cards.slice(3).map(renderCard(configTwo))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I can convert the last function from an arrow to a named function like this

```js
const renderCard = React.useMemo(
  () => (config) =>
    function ICard(card, i) {
      return (
        <div {...config} key={i}>
          <Card Icon={card.Icon} label={card.label} />
        </div>
      );
    },
  [cards]
);
```

I hope this helps someone else too